# Android - How to know if the Google Map is ready?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have created a `SupportMapFragment` dynamically, because I have some nested fragments and doing it with a `<fragment>` was crashing my app (`FragmentTabHost` doesn't play nice with `<fragment>` when you change tabs).

Now I want to do a simpel `getMap()` call but I always get `null`. I have called it from `onCreate` and from `onCreateView`...so far I have researched, this is because the fragment is still not created, so probably doing it in `onResume` is not a sure bet either, since the

```
 getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_frame, mMapFragment).commit();
```

is an Asynchronous call.

So my question is: How can I know that my Map is ready to be used? Is it there any `listeners` that can be used for this? Any common way of doing it? I can't find much in the docs about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know the map is ready to get used when using the SupportMapFragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047257/how-do-i-know-the-map-is-ready-to-get-used-when-using-the-supportmapfragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the other answers I made a much simpler option myself:

```
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                setupMapIfNeeded();
                return view;
            }
        };
```

This way, I extend the `SupportMapFragment` anonymously, and I don't need to create a new class or interfaces or listeners. Although if you need to reuse things and can benefit for more complex use cases, I recommend you to extend it in a new class and setup some listnets, but for my purpouse this was more than necessary.

Word of advice: Using it this way you can't use the factory method `newInstance()` of the `SupportMapFragmet`, so you will have to use the constructor, which for me is working just fine, but some advice to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to obtain the map object before the fragment has finished being created. using a LocationClient may help you, as mentioned by this gentleman 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804643/2818782).

One would call `locationClient.connect();` to establish connection. Upon a successful connection the onConnected method is executed. If it fails, onConnectionFailed is called.

[Google's example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) or this [example](https://github.com/gfx/AndroidLocationClientExample/blob/master/src/com/example/locationexample/MainActivity.java) should help you along.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday, and using this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303445/3309883