Getting location updates more than once a second
I have created an activity that is used to mesaure the acceleration or the brakes of a motorcycle (or any other driving unit).
For that reason I need location updates for at least 10 times a second.
actually i request for updates with
m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 50, (float) 0.1, m_locationListener);

and using a timer
    public void createGpsTimer( int interval )
    {
        if (m_gpsTimer!=null)
        {
            m_gpsTimer.cancel();
        }
        if( interval > 0 )
        {
            m_gpsInterval = interval;
            m_gpsTimer = new CountDownTimer(100000000, interval) {
                
                private Location m_lastKnown=null;
        
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Location newLocation = m_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (newLocation != null && (m_lastKnown==null || !m_lastKnown.equals(newLocation)))
                    {
                        lockLocationChanged(newLocation);
                    }
                }
            
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    m_gpsTimer.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
        else
        {
            m_gpsTimer = null;
            m_gpsInterval = 0;
        }
    }


I expect that getLastKnownLocation updates the position in time (10Hz).
Complete source is here: https://github.com/mgaeckler1964/TessTacho/tree/main
I have tested with
Samsung S5 Mini with Android 6,
Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 with Android 9,
Fairphone 3 with Android 13 and
Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 with Android 14

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16713659/295004

GPS is designed with one fix per second. There may be tricks to get more accurate data but you need better hardware (and antenna). Also some more expensive hardware come with inertial sensors, to provide data (e.g. in tunnels) when GPS is not available. Also I'm not sure if common chips are designed for such precision (so getting fix on all satellites at once, without delay). I would go directly with the accelerometer sensor of the phone (and maybe GPS to calibrate when things are smooth)
